# No se me visualizan los emojis en el navegador

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, libreria

No me cargan los emojis cuando lo pruebo en Visual Studio Code, **curiosamente en el editor de Stackoverflow si funcionan**, de pronto alguna sugerencia o el porque no me funciona?

Asi me aparece en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Definir la función replaceShortnames
    function replaceShortnames(text) {
      var regex = /:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+:/g;
      return text.replace(regex, function(shortname) {
        var emoji = emojione.shortnameToUnicode(shortname);
        return emoji;
      });
    }
  
    // Obtener todos los elementos que contienen shortnames de EmojiOne
      var emojiText = document.getElementById('user-name-id');
  
    // Iterar sobre cada elemento y reemplazar los shortnames con emojis Unicode
      
      emojiText.innerHTML = replaceShortnames(emojiText.innerHTML);
      console.log("EMOJIS CARGADOS!!!");
      console.log(emojiText);
      
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emojione@4.5.0/extras/css/emojione.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emojione@4.5.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script>
    <title>Emojis Unicode</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h5 id="user-name-id" class="user-name">Andres Lopez  :joy::sweat_smile::heart_eyes:</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simplemente no tienes referenciado el js en el html
Añade esta línea sustituyendo "test"
Por el nombre de tu JS <script src='test.js'></script>

Comment: Seguro que estás enlazando bien tu archivo js?...